# development documents on opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

Most opencv documents I have read are about how to use the classes and functions insider this great library. However, develop documents on opencv are few, especially documents on how to design and develop this libraries from a software developer's perspective. For example, `cv::Mat` is well designed to use the reference counting scheme and avoid deep-copying as much as possible, but the documents on how to realize it are few. So my questions is are there some documents or books available on this topic? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/), there are always more tutorials/user guides. There is also a [dedicated Q&A forum](http://answers.opencv.org/questions/) (quite the same as here though) and a [wiki](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki) which is more developper oriented